# How to remove all lines except .c extention(at last) lines using perl scripting

Tags: perl, operator-keyword

I've a string $string which has got list of lines, some ending with *.c, *.pdf,etc and few without any extensions(these are directories). I need to remove all lines except *.c lines. How can i do that using regular expression? I've written to get removed *.c files as below but how to do a not of it?

```
next if $line =~ /(\.c)/i;
```

Any ideas.

thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 2):

Use `unless` instead of `if` to reverse the sense of the condition.

```
next unless $line =~ /\.c$/i;
```

or simply invert the test:

```
next if $line !~ /\.c$/i;
```

Also, you don't need parentheses around the regexp, and you need `$` to anchor it to the end of the line.